# Почему ob.style, ob.height, ob.width не вызывают ошибки, ведь на доступ к ним наложены ограничения

Tags: java

```
 class TwoDShape {
    private double width;
    private double height;

    TwoDShape() {
        width = height = 0.0;
    }

    TwoDShape(double w, double h) {
        width = w;
        height = h;
    }

    TwoDShape(double x) {
        width = height = x;
    }

    TwoDShape(TwoDShape ob) {
        width = ob.width;
        height = ob.height;
    }

    double getWidth() { return width; }
    double getHeight() { return height; }
    void setWidth(double w) { width = w; }
    void setHeight(double h) { height = h; }

    void showDim() {
        System.out.println("Ширина и высота - " + width + " и " +
                height);
    }
}

class Triangle extends TwoDShape {
    private String style;

    Triangle() {
        super();
        style = "none";
    }

    Triangle(String s, double w, double h) {
        super(w, h);
        
        style = s;
    }

    Triangle(double x) {
        super(x);

        style = "закрашенный";
    }

    Triangle(Triangle ob) {
        super(ob);
        style = ob.style;
    }

    double area() {
        return getWidth() * getHeight() / 2;
    }

    void showStyle() {
        System.out.println("Треугольник " + style);
    }
}

class Shapes7 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Triangle t1 = new Triangle("контурный", 8.0, 12.0);

        Triangle t2 = new Triangle(t1);
        System.out.println("Информация о t1: ");
        t1.showStyle();
        t1.showDim();
        System.out.println("Площадь - " + t1.area());

        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("Информация о t2: ");
        t2.showStyle();
        t2.showDim();
        System.out.println("Площадь - " + t2.area());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Модификаторы доступа работают на уровне классов. Вот выдержка из [официальной оракловской документации](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html):

> Access level modifiers determine whether other classes can use a particular field or invoke a particular method. There are two levels of access control,

Хоть вы и обращаетесь к полю условно другого объекта (хотя спокойно можете передать в метод ссылку на самого себя), класс, у которому пренадлежит объект такой же как и класс объекта из которого Вы осуществляете досуп к полям. Поэтому такой доступ возможен.